# How to divide this string in multiple columns?

Tags: r, string

I've this string and I need to split it into different columns

```
legend = "Frequency..Derivatives.measure...Derivatives.instrument...Derivatives.risk.category...Derivatives.reporting.country...Derivatives.counterparty.sector...Derivatives.counterparty.country...Derivatives.underlying.risk.sector...Derivatives.currency.leg.1...Derivatives.currency.leg.2...Derivatives.maturity...Derivatives.rating...Derivatives.execution.method...Derivatives.basis...Period..30.06.1998.31.12.1998.30.06.1999.31.12.1999.30.06.2000.31.12.2000.30.06.2001.31.12.2001.30.06.2002.31.12.2002.30.06.2003.31.12.2003.30.06.2004.31.12.2004.30.06.2005.31.12.2005.30.06.2006.31.12.2006.30.06.2007.31.12.2007.30.06.2008.31.12.2008.30.06.2009.31.12.2009.30.06.2010.31.12.2010.30.06.2011.31.12.2011.30.06.2012.31.12.2012.30.06.2013.31.12.2013.30.06.2014.31.12.2014.30.06.2015.31.12.2015.30.06.2016.31.12.2016.30.06.2017.31.12.2017.30.06.2018.31.12.2018.30.06.2019"
```

Every three points there should be a new column, until the word *perdiod*. Note that the first word `Frequency` is divided from the second word `Derivatives.measure` *by only two points not three*.

After that, there are a series of Date (6 months interval) and they should be divided in this way: "everytime there's a 4 digit number perform a split".

How can I do this? Thank You

Comment: Do you expect "Derivatives.basis...Period..30.06.1998" to become 2 columns or 3?

Comment: @camille period could also be cancelled, anyway they should become 3 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` to split at the `...` with `fixed = TRUE` into a `list` of vectors and then `rbind` the vectors to create a `data.frame`

```
df1 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(legend, "...", fixed = TRUE))
names(df1) <- paste0("V", seq_along(df1))
```

---

If we also need to include the last condition to split the "Period"

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
tibble(col = legend) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(col, sep= "[.]{3}") %>%
  mutate(rn2 = str_c("V", rowid(rn))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = rn2, values_from = col) %>% 
  rename_at(ncol(.), ~ "Period") %>% 
  mutate(Period = str_remove(Period, "Period\\.+")) %>% 
  separate_rows(Period, sep="(?<=\\.[0-9]{4})\\.")
```

Comment: This is and works great! thank you. Can I ask you why using:  strsplit(legend, "...") without fixed = TRUE, the output gives back empty elements?

Comment: @Carlo By default, the `split` evalues for regex i.e. `fixed = FALSE` (default), so, wiith regex, the `.` is considered a meta character to match any character unless we escape `\\.` or place it inside square. brackeets `[.]`